# How to show different tables as a questionnaire?

Tags: php, sql

I got a huge database with different questions. Those questions are coupled with dimensions.

For example:

- Dimensions "Feelings"
- Question: How do you feel today?

I have to fetch those questions into a table which was fairly easy.

Now i have to build it like a questionnaire. Different questions related to topics. Each site contains different questions to the topic.

I got 9 different topics, how do I write that code in PHP on only one .php file?

The user should also be able to go forward with a next button and go back with a back button ( that's an easy one).

I just need an idea how to do the table questionnaire thing.

Comment: So you want a page for every dimension, then add the dimension as url parameter. Then you fetch your questions based on the url parameter with a default for the first dimension. Do validate this url parameter so you don't open sql injection possibilities.

Comment: thats what i really do not want, i do not want to add the dimensions as url paramets, else i would have like 9 different new pages, everything should be generated from one page. The tl dr would be : a next button shouldnt open a totally new .php site instead use the one which i am on

Comment: I did not mean a new php file, just a different url parameter towards the same php file. A parameter by which you determine what results to retrieve from the database.